# Changing User Permission

Tags: user

Can somebody help me how to change user permission listed in http://ap1.salesforce.com/help/doc/en/enabling_managed_packages.htm ?

Comment: if you feel the answers provided here have actually answered your queries, pls mark it as answered

Answer (score 1):

You will find these on profiles (setup -> Admin -> Manage Users -> Profiles)

**UPDATED:**
Open a profile and look under 
Administrator Permissions/General User Permissions.

[image]
[image]

Comment: I could not see listed permissions in User's profile.

Comment: Add screenshots, maybe those will help.